# Drop Connect Back Propagation

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, dropconnect

I'm trying to implement drop connect.  Am I supposed to use the same drop masks during back propagation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because back propagation is for computing gradients.

If some connection is blocked by the mask, it contributes nothing to the loss, so its associated gradient should be zero.